# How to control the string bold with coreText？？？

Tags: ipad, core-text, nsattributedstring

```
CGFloat widthValue = -1.0;

CFNumberRef strokeWidth = CFNumberCreate(NULL,kCFNumberFloatType,&widthValue);

//Setup the attributes dictionary with font and color
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            (id)font, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                            _fontColor.CGColor, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            strokeWidth,kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName,
                            nil];
```

I set the kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName with the above code ,but it is still bold.

I don't want the string to be bold.

How i can control it ????

Answer (score 0):

Checkout `kCTFontWeightTrait` and `kCTFontBoldTrait`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `widthValue` to:

```
CGFloat widthValue = 0.f;
```

to remove the bold text.

From Apple's docs:

> kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName
>       The stroke width. Value must be a CFNumberRef object. Default value is 0.0, or no stroke. This attribute, interpreted as a
>   percentage of font point size, controls the text drawing mode:
>   positive values effect drawing with stroke only; negative values are
>   for stroke and fill. A typical value for outlined text is 3.0.

Comment: @MarkLinus actually it does, the `kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName` attribute is how you control the boldness of text, here he has his `widthValue` set to `-1`, which emboldens text. I've added clarification.